# Rails not showing validation errors when failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I'm using ruby 3.0.2 on rails 7.0.4 and tailwind.

I have a simple model with a simple validation, and general validation behaviour is working as expected,i.e. errors show when testing in console and in the browser, the form does not submit as expected - so I know the validation is working behind the scenes. If I fill the field, the form submits.

The issue is that the validation errors are not being triggered on the form. Manipulating the errors block confirms that the text would appear as specified. I wonder if this has anything to do with turbo not updating the screen?:

Model:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Form:

````
      <% if @account.errors.any? %>
        <div class="text-red-700">
          <h4>
            <%= "#{pluralize(@account.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this account from being saved:" %>
          </h4>
          <ul>
            <% @account.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>%
              <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :name, class: 'block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900' %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Enter your Account\'s Name', class: 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5' %>
      </div>
    <%=f.submit "Save", class: "text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center" %>
  <% end %>```

Thanks in advance!
````

Comment: can you show us controller code it is needed to understand the problem

Comment: thanks! I must have got your vibes...about the same time you posted this, I...well...you'll see below. The issue was indeed my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I see I didn't include the controller in the question, that was the issue. It didn't occur to me that I was blindly following a (paid) ebook. Upon checking a controller on a previous project of mine, I found the action in the controller didn't have the status for the render in the else section. Here's how it should have been [after I fixed it]:

```
def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      current_user.account = @account
      current_user.add_role :admin, @account
      current_user.save
      redirect_to root_path, success: "Your account has been created!"
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```